# Two errors "Type is not known on line" when I run `sudo apt-get update`

Tags: apt, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get these errors:

```
E: Type 'See' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-tor64-saucy.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-tor64-saucy.list` contains garbage on line 1. Open the file in a text editor with root privileges (eg use `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-tor64=saucy.list` or instead of `nano` use `sudo -H gedit`).

Look for the word `dep` at the start of the line. This looks like a typo; the line should begin with `deb`. If you cannot fix the line yourself, delete the file, and try adding the PPA again.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` contains garbage on line 2. Probably the offending line starts with the word `See`. You can delete the line, or comment it out by placing a `#` at the start of the line.

The entries in this file normally follow this format:

```
deb http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3
deb-src http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3
```